# Не могу запустить Jupyter Notbook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Не могу запустить Jupyter Notbook.
C:\Users\Влад\jupyter>jupyter-notebook
"jupyter-notebook" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Устанавливал через pip install jupyter
Всё установилось корректно
ОС:Windows 10

Comment: `jupyter notebook` - раздельно и без дефиса

Comment: C:\Users\Влад>jupyter notebook
"jupyter" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

C:\Users\Влад>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяем, что пакет дейсвительно установлен в системе

```
~> pip show jupyter
```

Получаем что-то вроде такого вывода, обращаем внимание на `Location`:

```
Name: jupyter
Version: 1.0.0
Summary: Jupyter metapackage. Install all the Jupyter components in one go.
Home-page: http://jupyter.org
Author: Jupyter Development Team
Author-email: jupyter@googlegroups.org
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\alex\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages
Requires: ipywidgets, jupyter-console, nbconvert, ipykernel, notebook, qtconsole
Required-by:
```

Если все хорошо, то можно запустить Jupyter через команду `python -m notebook`

Причина, почему он нормально не запускается в том, что в переменную окружение не попал путь до запуска исполняемого файла. Переходим в путь, куда python устанавливает пакеты (`Location` из вывода выше). Переходим на директорию выше, там должна быть папка 'Scripts', где лежит `jupyter.exe`.

Чтобы запускать как обычно, добавляем эту папку `Scripts` в переменные окружения PATH, после должен работать обычный `~> jupyter notebook` и `~> jupyter-notebook`.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо =)

Answer (score -1):

для того чтобы не возникало такой ошибки, при установке anaconda нужно выбрать галочку `add anaconda 3 to the system PATH`